# How to select objects from a list where attributes fall between a certain year range in c#?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list of Car objects as follows:

```
    private List<Car> Fleet = new List<Car>()
    {
       new Car("Toyota", "Corola","YI348J", 2007, 7382.33),
       new Car("Renault", "Megane","ZIEKJ", 2001, 1738.30),
       new Car("Fiat", "Punto","IUE748", 2004, 3829.33)
    };
```

I would like to use the following method to return a new list of cars where the year (3rd attribute in list above) falls between 'fromYear' and 'toYear':

```
    public List<Car> getCars(int fromYear, int toYear)
    {

        return newList
    }
```

The car class has a getYear() property.

Comment: `getDate()` is not a property but a method. Either case it should start with a capital letter in C#. This is not Java! :-) (Same applies to the `getCars` method.

Comment: and while you're at it, fields are *generally* (again, purely convention) named lower case, so: `private List<Car> fleet ...`

Comment: Thanks! Yeah i edited the getDate to getYear.

Comment: While that is a nice approach, it is still "wrong". It should either be `GetYear()` or `Year`. The former is a method, the latter is a property. There should be no properties named `Get...`. Again, this is not Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like:

```
return Fleet.FindAll(car => car.Year >= fromYear && car.Year <= toYear);
```

assuming a `Car` has a `Year`. The thing inside the brackets is an *lambda expression* that describes a *predicate* (aka a filter); for every `car`, it returns `true` if the `car.Year` is in the range, `false` otherwise; `FindAll` applies the predicate to each item and returns a list of those for which the predicate returned `true`.

This is semantically equivalent to the LINQ version:

```
return Fleet.Where(car => car.Year >= fromYear && car.Year <= toYear).ToList();
```

but more direct.

Comment: The car class seems to have a `getDate()` property (which would technically be a method)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar well, without visibility of the type, I'm loathe to make too many assumptions about what the `getDate()` method returns ;p If it returns a `DateTime` (as you might expect for a method named `getDate()`), it would of course be `.getDate().Year`, but... who knows?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public List<Car> getCars(int fromYear, int toYear)
    {
        var carsList = Fleet
                 .Where(c => c.Year >= fromYear && c.Year <= toYear).ToList();
        return carsList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work. It creates a new list and iterates through all the cars in your list `Fleet` and checks if its year is within the range. If it is, then the car gets added to the list which is returned after all cars have been checked

```
public List<Car> getCars(int fromYear, int toYear)
    {
        List<Car> newList = new List<Car>();
        foreach (Car c in Fleet)
        {
            if(c.getDate() < toYear)
            {
                if (c.getDate() > fromYear)
                {
                    newList.Add(c);
                }
            }
        }
        return newList;
    }
```

Comment: I have made the assumption from your constructor and method that the date is stored as an int